# Auto Play YouTube Video Without Slowing Down Page Load Time

Tags: performance, video, youtube, pagespeed, autoplay

I've had a scan through previous questions and can't seem to find anything about adding a YouTube video to a page and having it auto play without effecting page load speeds. Is there anyway to allow the full content of the page to carry on loading without the Video creating a bottle neck situation?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the device and browser but on a laptop, using the HTML5 video mechanism your page will continue to load while the video starts on most OS's and browsers, without you having to do any complicated ordering.

The video is streamed, which in practice means small chunks are requested at a time, so there is no delay waiting for the full video to download. Most browsers will implement this playback in a way that does not interfere with the rest of the page download and display - e.g. in a separate thread, and even sometimes mostly in the device HW itself.

On a mobile device things are different - many mobile devices will not allow autoplay at all. They implement this restriction protect to the user from incurring excessive charges on mobile data plans.

Many mobile deices will also force the video to play full screen when it does play - this tends to be on a device by device basis. For example iPhones play videos full screen but larger iPad's will allow it inline in the web page (this is an ever changing playing field so its worth checking the status with the latest release if you are interested in a  particular device).

Answer (score 1):

Searching around on line I came across this little bit of javascript, and an amend to the YouTube embed code which helped.

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ihhAswAsg8c?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Notice how the src="" is empty and the url has been put inside a data-src="" instead. Then add the following javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function init() {
        var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
            if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
});
```

This will then stop the iframe from automatically making lots of http requests until the rest of the page has finished loading.